# Servlet Container (Tomcat) ou Application Server?

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, cdi, ejb

Atualmente estou desenvolvendo um projeto que utilizo JSF, JPA, CDI e EJB. Li em diversos locais onde afirmaram que Tomcat (Servlet Container) não possui suporte a estas tecnologias, porém atualmente estou usando o Tomcat e faço uso de todas estas tecnologias através da importação pelo Maven.

O benefício do Application Server é somente que ele já trás estas dependências pré-configuradas dentro dele? Ou existe algo a mais? Qual a vantagem que eu poderia ter ao trocar para um Application Server atualmente, visto que já possuo minhas dependências supridas através do Maven?

Outra dúvida relacionada ao EJB. Eu utilizo somente o `@Stateless` até o momento. Para injeção estou utilizando `@Inject` no lugar de `@EJB`, com isso estou utilizando EJB, certo? Ou estou confundindo alguma coisa?

Comment: Primeiro, há duas perguntas diferentes aqui. A primeira é que servidor de aplicação é que nem time de futebol, cada um tem a sua preferência. Além disso, os diversos servidores de aplicação são bem diferentes entre si (Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish, Wildfly, Websphere, etc), então tem várias opções diferentes para vários gostos diferentes. Quanto a segunda parte da sua pergunta, acho que isso deve esclarecer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4684112/540552

Comment: Agradeço a sua resposta. Eu entendo que existem diversos Application Servers diferentes, porém o conceito de Application Server é geral. É uma ferramenta completa que fornece o suporte para todos os frameworks que citei. A questão é que eu consigo utilizar todos eles no meu Servlet Container (Tomcat 8), que segundo muitos posts que vi pela internet, não suporta tais tecnologias, limitando-se somente ao JSP/Servlet. Por isso minha dúvida. O "suporte" fornecido pelo Application Server é somente trazer consigo as dependências que eu tive que importar pelo Maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EJB é uma tecnologia para o desenvolvimento de aplicações distribuídas. Os diferentes servidores de aplicação efetuam a distribuição de forma diferente. O EJB, o CDI, o JSP e o JSF são apenas especificações, e as implementações específicas de cada container variam bastante. Todos eles têm extensões proprietárias não portáveis.

Esses servidores de aplicação implementam EJB, JSP, Servlets, CDI e outras coisas, mas o fazem de formas diferentes. Até mesmo no JSP, cada container o compila de um jeito diferente. Eles também são configurados e administrados de formas bem diferentes e incompatíveis entre si.

Simplesmente juntar um monte de dependências com o Maven em um servidor de aplicação qualquer não funciona porque cada servidor têm as suas dependências específicas e incompatíveis com os demais. Nesse caso, você precisa colocar as dependências compatíveis com o servidor de aplicação no caso. Porém para isso, você não precisa do Maven, porque essas dependências já estão lá.

Por exemplo, o Wildfly utiliza o Weld para prover o CDI. Se você tentar usar o Weld para isso no Glassfish ou no Tomcat, ele vai falhar terrivelmente.

O Tomcat e o Jetty não são servidores EJB, implementam apenas a parte do Servlet e JSP. Entretanto, é possível utilizar o OpenEJB como dependência Maven para adicionar o EJB ao Tomcat (e acredito que no Jetty também, mas não tenho certeza). Nos demais servidores de aplicação, isso não faria sentido e provavelmente nem funcionaria porque eles já tem as suas próprias implementações de EJB/CDI/etc.

Além disso, o Jetty por exemplo, tem uma implementação própria de websockets não portável para outros servidores de aplicação. O pacote de COMET do Glassfish não roda em nenhum outro servidor de aplicação que não o Glassfish.

O Jersey é a implementação do JAX-RS para o Glassfish enquanto que o RestEasy é a do Wildfly. Além de serem implementações do JAX-RS, também são extensões dele. Ou seja, há coisas que existem no RestEasy que não existem no Jersey e vice-versa. Tentar usar o RestEasy no Glassfish ou o Jersey no Wildfly vai resultar em erros na implantação. Adicionar algum pacote qualquer no classpath ao usar o Maven não vai resolver o problema.

Outra diferença forte entre os servidores de aplicação concerne no uso de MDBs. Há diferentes ferramentas que implementam as filas de mensagerias dos MDBs, e essas ferramentas frequentemente são acopladas a servidores de aplicação específicos.

Ou seja, todos os servidores de aplicação têm recursos **exclusivos** que não tem como ser adicionados aos demais por meio do maven (ou qualquer outr coisa que os coloque no classpath) por serem fortemente amarrados a detalhes internos do servidor de aplicação que o disponibiliza.

E essa é a armadilha dos servidores de aplicação. A ideia do "*Write Once, Run Everywhere*" e da portabilidade são apenas meias-verdades. O fato é que nos servidores de aplicação, o código é portável enquanto manter-se rigorosamente dentro do padrão, mas todos eles têm bibliotecas, configurações e mecanismos específicos e exclusivos de cada servidor de aplicação que vão dificultar a sua vida caso queira fazer uma migração ou adicionar dependências que tentem extender as capacidades do servidor de aplicação.

---

Quanto ao `@Inject` no lugar de `@EJB` é porque o CDI é mais novo que o EJB. O EJB tem um mecanismo de injeção de dependência que permite injetar EJBs (anotados com `@Stateless`, `@Stateful` ou `@Singleton`) em locais anotados com `@EJB` (há outras anotações para injetar outras coisas, tal como `@Resource` e `@PersistenceContext`).

Quando o CDI foi concebido, a anotação para a injeção de dependências criada foi o `@Inject`. Para ter interoperabilidade com o EJB, o CDI também reconhece o `@EJB`.

Comment: Entendi a parte do Inject e EJB, muito obrigado!
Em relação a parte do servidor de aplicação, então caso eu quisesse mudar do atual Tomcat 8 para o Glassfish por exemplo, minhas vantagens seriam basicamente retirar algumas coisas do meu Maven e utilizar alguns recursos a mais (como o que você falou do MDB), visto que já consigo utilizar CDI, JSF, etc?
Para esclarecer mais uma coisa, atualmente eu consigo utilizar o Stateless sem ter feito a importação do OpenEJB, isso quer dizer que o Tomcat já possui essa dependência? Ou "utilizar EJB" seria algum outro recurso que não senti falta ainda?

Comment: @Thiago Não. As vantagens não são retirar algumas coisas do maven. O Glassfish tem recursos exclusivos que não podem ser adicionados no Glassfish por meio do maven. Cada um dos demais também tem recursos exclusivos. O Tomcat não tem essa dependência com o OpenEJB. Pelo contrário, a ideia dele é ser um container que seja mais leve justamente por não ter o EJB.

Comment: Certo. Muito obrigado pelas respostas!